# jQuery bug. Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).chosen is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a bug in my JavaScript that I have tried to fix.

MY Chrome says: `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).chosen is not a function`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery('select.scan_action').chosen();
  jQuery('#barcode-scan-form input#scan-code').focus(function () {
    jQuery(this).select()
  });
  jQuery('#barcode-scan-form input#scan-code').scannerDetection(function () {
    jQuery('#barcode-scan-form form').submit()
  });
  jQuery('#barcode-scan-form form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#barcode-scan-loader').show();
    jQuery('#barcode-scan-result').html('');
    var t = jQuery('#barcode-scan-form input#scan-code').val(),
    n = jQuery('#barcode-scan-form #scan-action').val();
    jQuery.post(wc_order_barcodes.ajaxurl, {
      action: 'scan_barcode',
      barcode_input: t,
      scan_action: n,
      woocommerce_order_barcodes_scan_nonce: wc_order_barcodes.scan_nonce
    }).done(function (e) {
      jQuery('#barcode-scan-form input#scan-code').focus();
      if (!e) return;
      jQuery('#barcode-scan-loader').hide();
      jQuery('#barcode-scan-result').html(e)
    })
  })
});
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like you need to install the plugin. http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: it worked to you before? if not check for the setup again: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#setup

Comment: You need to enqueue `chosen` jquery plugin before you use it.